# using the hook_nodeapi in the view mode

Tags: forms

I am trying to add a form when I view my node; for that I am using the following code.

```
function review_m_nodeapi(&$node, $op, $a3 = NULL, $a4 = NULL){
    switch($op){
        case view:
```

In this case I would like to call `drupal_get_form()`.

I would like to add the following code.

```
function review_m_form($node) {
    $form = array();
    $form['mark'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Give a mark to the content type(1 to 10)!',
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 2,
    );
    $form['text'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => 'leave a feedback!',
        '#cols' => 60,
        '#resizable' => FALSE,
        '#rows' => 5,
    );
    $form['created'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => 'Enter the date!',
        '#size' => 60,
        '#maxlength' => 10,
    );
    $form['submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Send review'),
        '#weight' => 10,
    );
    return $form;
}
```

How can I pass this in the view case, so that it works good for me?

I am trying something like the following code.

```
case view:
            $node->content['form'] = array(
                drupal_get_form('review_m_form'),
              );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the first required variable in the signature of your form declaration so things will never work quite as you're expecting.

The function signature should be:

```
function review_m_form(&$form_state, $node) {
```

Then you would attach it to your node content like so, remembering to pass the node as a parameter:

```
$node->content['form'] = drupal_get_form('review_m_form', $node);
```